# linq query using joins and aggregate functions

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, linq, sql-server-2008

I want to write a linq query which retrieves the data in the following format.

Assume that there are two tables - `Department` and `Employee`

```
Department
Dept_id| Manager_id   

Employee
Emp_id| Dept_id| Emp_data
```

The relationship between `Department` and `Employee` table is one to many. The `Department` table also stores the manager employee id in that particular department. So `Manager_id` is nothing but the `employee_id`.

Now I want to get the data as follows

```
Dept_id, Manager_id, Emp_data(data of Manager_id), Count(employees in that department)
```

If I do the join on two tables i can get data of Manager but unable to get the count of all employees in that department. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please mention which query you have tried

Comment: Please post some sample data and expected output.

Comment: You have to join Employee table Twice First for Manager Data and Second time for Count of Employee.

Comment: @Devuser when asking a question, and receiving some answers it would seem to be common courtesy to at least comment on them. Could you please do so, or alternatively, if you have solved this problem yourself post that as the answer.

Comment: Thanks Alex. I used the solution provided by Arion

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
var result= 
    (
        from dep in db.Department
        join emp in db.Employee
            on dep.Manager_id equals emp.Emp_id
        select new
        {
            dep.Dept_id,
            emp,
            NumberOfEmp= db.Employee.Count(c=>c.Dept_id==dep.Dept_id)
        }
    ).ToList();
```

Where `db` is the linq data context

Comment: Thanks. But its like querying the employee table twice. Considering the performance impact, Is there any way we can get the information by joining once

Comment: @Devuser : No, because you are using different keys

Answer (score 0):

You could do a group join. If you have a preferred handcoded SQL statement that you would like to be generated from your LINQ query. You may want to experiment a bit with different formats to see which one allows you to generate the "best" SQL.

```
var result = from d in context.Departments
             join e in context.Employees on d.dept_id equals e.dept_id into g
             select new {
                 dept_id = d.dept_id,
                 manager_id = d.manager_id,
                 manager_data = g.Single(x => x.emp_id == d.manager_id).emp_data,
                 employee_count = g.Count()
             };
```

or

```
var result = from d in context.Departments
             join e in context.Employees on d.dept_id equals e.dept_id into g
             from m in g where m.emp_id == d.manager_id
             select new {
                 dept_id = d.dept_id,
                 manager_id = d.manager_id,
                 manager_data = m.emp_data,
                 employee_count = g.Count()
             };
```